# iOS: Fatal Exception: NSRangeException *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, crash, nsarray

this is the crash I am receiving right now. Can someone please help me figure out how to resolve this? It occurs on this line `UITableViewCell* cell=[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[_tableView    indexPathForRowAtPoint:point]];` I thought if I check if indexPath was valid it would resolve it, but it didn't. Any way to stop this from occurring? Any tips or suggestions are appreciated. I will post what I tried to do below.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
if (indexPath) {
UITableViewCell* cell=[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[_tableView    indexPathForRowAtPoint:point]];
.... rest of my code
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You might reload the table view before initialising array , or may be your array is empty when you use it !

Like when you use :

```
NSString *xyz = [self.your_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

in cellForRowAtIndexPath , Try fllowing code that wont crash your app !

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"xyz_cell";
long nodeCount = [self.your_array count];

if (nodeCount == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
{
    Home_CellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[Home_CellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
        cell.lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    cell.lbl.text = @"No Posts yet !";

    return cell;
}


else{

Home_CellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[Home_CellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
} // Your Code Goes HERE .... NSString *xyz = [self.your_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; }
```

so , for empty array it wont find value for key one and your app wont crash !

I hope it helps ,

Answer (score 0):

Your tableView doesn't have more than a single row I suspect (or none?).

As your error message indicates, you're trying to reference object at index 1, but the bounds of the array are 0 .. 0.

If you're executing this before the tableView is initialized you'll need to change where you execute it, or perhaps you forgot to implement the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` delegate method?

Answer (score 0):

As you told in your question that error coming in this line, it means that indexPath is holding some reference Try change this line

```
if (indexPath) {
    UITableViewCell* cell=[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[_tableView  indexPathForRowAtPoint:point]];
}
```

to

```
if (indexPath) {
        UITableViewCell* cell=[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
    }
```

But, i suspect that you are not having more than 1 item in your tableview.